# Stripe checkout event for failed payments

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have a paid membership site which takes payments via Stripe [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) ([server integration](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server)). When a user registers, they are redirected to the Stripe checkout (with their ID passed as the 'client_reference_id') where they enter their card details. For the [checkout fulfillment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment), I have a [webhook](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment#webhooks) setup that is linked to the event '[checkout.session.complete](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed)'.

Everything is working fine, the webhook triggers and the endpoint processes the data and marks the corresponding account as activated, sends an email to the account holder as well as the site admin to let them both know the account has been created and a payment has been successful.

However, if a payment fails, I don't know what event to attach to the webhook to detect failed payments via Stripe Checkout. The only checkout event documented is 'checkout.session.complete', there isn't one for something like 'checkout.session.failed'. There's 'invoice.payment_failed' but this is used in subscriptions not one-off checkout payments.

We're wanting to basically notify the site admin when a payment fails so they are aware an account has been created but it still awaiting payment.

Is there a checkout event I'm missing or another way to go about finding failed checkout transactions?

Comment: `charge.failed` webhook status

Comment: What's wrong with using the [`charge.failed`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-charge.failed) webhook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To charge a credit or a debit card, you create a `Charge` object. You can retrieve and refund individual charges as well as list all charges. Charges are identified by a unique, random ID.

-- From the Stripe [API Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges).

You can then detect a [`webhook` response](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) of `charge.failed` to show that an attempted use of a `charge` object [has failed](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-charge.failed).

Stripe used to be very cleanly documented, but they've lost their way a little, recently.

Stripe card payments **ALWAYS** use `Charge` objects, sometimes these are set by you (`invoices`, `subscriptions`, etc.) and sometimes these are set behind the scenes by Stripe ("Checkout Process", etc) -- but they are always set, so your webhook can always detect a `charge.failed` event.

---

## Addendum

> This does work, however, since the client_reference_id is not in the charge.failed data, I can't link the failed payment to a specific account anyway. But in regards to my actual question, this event does work and is the correct answer, just unfortunate that it doesn't solve my specific situation.

To solve this; either using the Stipe interface or by coding:

1) Create a `Customer` object and keep some sort of record of this customer Id.

2) When the Stripe `Charge` runs, an associated $charge->customer is set. This is available to your webhook.

3) When the webhook result appears, use this (typically) `$event->data->object->customer` value to cross reference the charge with the correct customer on your server.

4) As mentioned in comments, Stripe Webhook Testing does **not** populate the webhooks with example data such as `->customer`... `:-(`

Comment: As mentioned in the other comments, we're using checkout, I thought `charge.failed` is used with invoicing not the checkout session?

Comment: Charges are used whenever money is taken from a credit / debit card. It doesn't matter the source. So even if you're using Checkout, the `charge.failed` webhook will still trigger.

Comment: @no. as referenced by BenM; if you use Checkout you might not set up the `Charge` object yourself but Stripe will be using it on the backend of the transaction.

Comment: @no. I have found the test webhooks to be virtually useless. They don't populate the webhook data, so the testing only works in as far as passing the event name back to the server (in this case `charge.failed`)

Comment: @Martin This does work, however, since the `client_reference_id` is not in the `charge.failed` data, I can't link the failed payment to a specific account anyway. But in regards to my actual question, this event does work and is the correct answer, just unfortunate that it doesn't solve my specific situation. Appreciate the help and the knowledge that `Charge` objects are created regardless in Stripe.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit late for a reply - but I have a working solution!!

When I create a "Session" in Stripe, I make sure to fill out the SessionCreateOptions so that the PaymentIntentData.Metadata field is setup to have my customer's ID and stuff in it. When I do that, the metadata not only shows up in payment_intent.created and payment_intent.succeeded webhooks, but it ALSO shows up in charge.succeeded/failed!

This means that when a payment fails I can look up the attempted payment that I keep track of and email them back letting them know that it failed and why, and I can also log it for myself for reference when I go look up that customer in my customer service tools.

Comment: Are you referring to metadata? When I set those values in the Checkout Session, they do not appear in the charge.succeeded webhook or the PaymentIntent

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from the documentation and I spent a lot of time grokking how it works, so I hope this will save you some time.

The checkout session **CANNOT fail** (!)

A Checkout Session can have one of 3 states: "open" is an active session which can be paid, "completed" is paid ("happy path"), and "expired" if within the expiration time the session was not completed.

A session can only expire with two options:

1. After 24 hours if not paid (or sooner, if you set a shorter expiration time https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-expires_at)
2. Manually by calling https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/expire

A session's URL can be accessed unlimited number of times for payment attempts until it is either paid or expires. This is by design, so a user can have a couple of failed attempts to pay until she actually pays. With a session, you do not care about those attempts, and in most cases you do not need to track them.

So one option for your workflow can be the following, for example:

1. For creating a new order, create a new session, save it's ID in the order's record in the DB, and redirect the user to the session's URL
2. On the back-end, listen for "session completed" event, which is the happy path - everything is paid (watch out for the async payments, if you accept any! See herehttps://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#delayed-notification)
3. Also listen for "session expired" event. This will tell you that the user bailed and hasn't paid the order. You can send them a "failed payment, try again" email in this case (see below for Recovery workflow)
4. If the user returns to your website before paying for the order, you can display "NOT PAID, TRY AGAIN" message next to the unpaid order.

Attention: it is perfectly safe for the user to open a dozen of the session's URL and attempt to pay as Stripe won't allow the double payment after card information is submitted.

So you are thinking about creating expiring the old session and creating a new one for this unpaid order? Wrong! You can retrieve it by ID (you saved it in the DB, right?) and send the same URL to the user.

However, if the retrieved session is "expired", there will be no URL to send, so you will be forced to create a new session, save it in DB, and the whole cycle repeats.

Another possibility is for the repayment workflow to happen in rare state between the payment and "session is completed" webhook event (the user already paid in another tab, but you haven't received the "paid" event yet), you will get that the retrieved session state is "completed", in this case you will need the capability for the front-end not only to redirect the customer to a session's URL, but instead sometimes show a message like "nope, it's already paid".

As you can see, there is no "failed" state for the checkout session.

Now, another thing for recovering the unpaid and expired sessions is the Recovery workflow (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/abandoned-carts). The gist of it is the following:
When creating a session, you set "recovery" to true, so if the session expires, you will have access to a special URL that will "revive the same session with the same parameters" that will be active for 30 days after the original session expiration. You then send this URL to users with possibly some discount to recover their abandoned cart. Also, you can track whether the session is "original" or "revived". However, I did not use this way, and instead opted to simply creating a new session manually if the old one is expired.